# Is it possible to add another Window with XAML?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, window

I have a c# project in which I want to add another window. For example :

I click on a button and then another window pop. I was wondering if it is possible to configure another `MyNewWindow.cs` and `MyNewWindow.xaml` to configure my new window and to simply call that window in `MyOldWindowWhichHandleNewWindowButton.cs`.

If yes, how can I do that ? I tried manually add a new `xaml` and cs file but it seems like there is a conflict between both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click on your project in the solution explorer, and select add -> new item.

In the list of available new items, select "Window (WPF)." This will add both the *.CS and *.XAML files, and will automatically link them together to make the new window function.

You can then call the new window by using a variety of programmatic methods, depending on your needs.

For example:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window1 w1 = new Window1();
    w1.Show();
}
```